# Does 2 party consent apply if the data is anonymized?

Tags: united-states, data-protection, personal-information, artificial-intelligence, data-protection-act

If I have a text conversation between myself and another party, both of whom reside in 2 party consent states in the US, if I remove all reasonably identifying information, do I still need consent from the other person to use the data? Does this change if I am using it to fine-tune an LLM for public use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Consent only applies to audio recordings

Written communication (and, usually soundless video recording) is not covered.

Comment: Are there any other privacy laws that might be relevant? afaik CCPA and such only apply to businesses

Comment: If you have another question, ask another question.